# Keras: Max pool along 1 axis, Avg pool along another?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

In Keras, for my particular dataset of 2D images, I would like to try using max pooling along the horizontal axis and average pooling along the vertical. How do I do that?

(Currently I just have max pooling in both directions; I'm curious if a 'hybrid' pooling approach would work even better due to the specifics of my particular dataset.)

How can I do that?

1. My hope was to just call the MaxPooling1D and AveragePooling1D layers in succession for different axes, but I don't see any "axis=" keyword parameter available for these layers.
2. Just passing in a axis-subset of the tensor-data into a 1D pool or trying to slice the data: Sure, I'd be ok to try that if you think it's viable, but my experience with trying to slice TF tensors is that it can be really tricky; so I'm not confident about this but if you are let me know.
3. Alternatively, so far my attempt to write my own "HybridPooling2D" Layer has taken me deep down into a rabbit hole of tensorflow code calling more tensorflow code.  So, before I venture to try to write my own `tensorflow.python.ops.nn.hyb_pool()` type routine, I thought I'd pause and ask here on S.O. before proceeding.

One further optional request:  Because of legacy reasons, I'm still using `keras==2.1.3` and `tensorflow=1.14`. If answers given could still work with that (e.g. not require TF 2), that'd be great.  Because if I have to update those just to try out my idea, then it's probably not worth my time right now. Thanks.

**Update:** Along the lines of option 2 above, I'm trying to use Lambda's, sort of replacing (for `pool_size=(2,2)`)

```
    x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(x)
```

with something like...?

```
    x = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,0,:,:], output_shape=(??) + (input_shape[??]))(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=pool_size[0])(x)
    x = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,1,:], output_shape=(??) + input_shape[??]))(x)
    x = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=pool_size[1])(x)
```

...ish?  (I know that's wrong, I don't want to pool along just one row or one column, but instead along all rows and then along the single remaining column, or something.)  And yea, I know that Avg & Max operations done along different axes won't commute; I'm ok with that. This is just something to try.

Comment: I tried something like that, but its actually very anoying. I could try later a workarround, but why dont use tf2.0 ? you just need to change the imports from "import keras" to "import tensorflow.keras". Thats the magic and you can easily solve your problem without Lambda layers.

Comment: In the long run, updating would be advisable.  However, I had a different project in which I ended up getting very behind on after updating Keras, because of a fine point that had changed somehow deep inside Keras, that caused the training to become much less effective. I thought I'd introduced a bug but no.    Right now I don't have time to deal with any potential issues like that. The old "if it ain't broke..." adage. (Whereas just trying a new pooling scheme is 'optional'.)